# Display XML error received from server in a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, client, client-server

I have a web service from which I receive XML response. In jQuery I have the following, for getting a certain book:

```
function getBookByIsbn() {

if($("#getAndDeleteIsbn").val() == '')
{
    alert("Please provide the ISBN");
    return false;
}
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/library/books/' + $("#getAndDeleteIsbn").val(),
    success: function (data) {
        var string;
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
            string = data.xml;
        }
        else
        {
            string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data);
        }
            $("#messageBox").text(string);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, thrownError) {
        var string;
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
            string = thrownError.xml;
        }
        else
        {
            string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(thrownError);

        }
            $("#messageBox").text(string);
  }
});
}
```

Now, when the request is successful, the message is displayed, but when I receive an error, the content will not be displayed. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Someone adviced me to print all the three parameters in the console, so I've found out that actually the xhr parameter contains what I need. **The problem now is that if I try to create an alert(xhr.responseText), the alert window contains the desired message, but if I want to display the same thing inside the div, nothing happens, and I want it to be displayed there.**

Comment: what is an error ????"text  of error "

Comment: when something goes wrong on the server side, I throw a custom exception containing some XML and I want to display that XML in a div...for example, if the ISBN introduced by the user contains letters, I will receive <errorMessage><code>400 Bad Request</code><message>The ISBN must contain only digits!</message></errorMessage>...and I do receive this message in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I tryed to serialize a string to string, because xhr.responseText is a string. To solve the problem, instead of xhr.responseText, it should be xhr.responseXML.
Here is the code:

```
function getBookByIsbn() {


if($("#getAndDeleteIsbn").val() == '')
{
    alert("Please provide the ISBN");
    return false;
}
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/library/books/' + $("#getAndDeleteIsbn").val(),
    success: function (data) {
        var string;
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
            string = data.xml;
        }
        else
        {
            string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data);
        }
            $("#messageBox").text(string);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, thrownError) {
        var string;
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
            string = xhr.responseXML.xml;
        }
        else
        {
            string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xhr.responseXML);

        }
            $("#messageBox").text(string);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

server and getting response from server i am also getting the same thing . you just need to check either its an error or response. for that you can either use javascript xquery  or get the use.

```
  //suppose you get response in variable 'xml_response'.
 var res = xml_response.getElementByTagName('errorMessage');
 //if result exist then it is error other wise it is not error.
 if ( res[0] ){
  alert ( 'error occur on server side. ');
  return;
 }else{
 //show you record in div.
 }
```